# How to store two different things in one byte and then access them again?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am trying to learn C for my class. One thing I need to know is given an array, I have to take information from two characters and store it in one bytes. For eg. if string is "A1B3C5" then I have to store A = 001 in higher 3bits and then store 1 in lower 5bits. I have to function that can get two chars from array at a time and print it here is that function,

```
 void print2(char string[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int length = 0;
    char char1, char2;
    length = strlen(string);
    for ( i = 0; i <length; i= i + 2)
    {
        char1 = string[i];
        char2 = string[i+1];
        printf("%c, %c\n", char1, char2);
    }
}
```

but now i am not sure how to get it encoded and then decode again. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: If you manage to store two different values in an entity with two states, you deserve a Fields medal.

Comment: @pmr: he is clearly a beginner and probably mixed up bit and byte. Unfortunately, I can't edit the post! Why is that? I already edited a few today.

Comment: @mort - it's because you don't have permissions for this yet. But you can edit and wait for approving or rejecting your edit.

Comment: And I'd vote for rejecting such edit, as it changes the meaning of the question, this would be too radical edit.

Comment: @pmr: I don't see an edit link beneath the post as I used to. I know that I usually had to wait a view minutes for someone to review my edit, but here I can't even make one

Comment: @mort - you may want to ask/search for this on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Kiril: Thanks for the hint with meta. About rejecting the edit: I see your point, but right now it's difficult to find out what the question is about.

Comment: @Kiril: Interestingly, the edit link showed up again

Comment: @mort - exactly - "it's difficult to find out what the question is about", you said that, that's why nobody should do such radical edit - it may change the whole point of the question. That's why I wrote my first comment - the question should be paraphrased by the poster, IMO.

Comment: @Kiril: Ok, now I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an ASCII character set, subtract '@' from the letter and shift left five bits, then subtract '0' from the character representing the digit and add it to the first part.

Answer (score 2):

So you've got a byte, and you want the following bit layout:

```
76543210
AAABBBBB
```

To store `A`, you would do:

```
unsigned char result;
int input_a = somevalue;
result &= 0x1F; // Clear the upper 3 bits.
// Store "A": make sure only the lower 3 bits of input_a are used,
// Then shift it by 5 positions. Finally, store it by OR'ing.
result |= (char)((input_a & 7) << 5);
```

To read it:

```
// Simply shift the byte by five positions.
int output_a = (result >> 5);
```

To store `B`, you would do:

```
int input_b = yetanothervalue;
result &= 0xE0; // Clear the lower 5 bits.
// Store "B": make sure only the lower 5 bits of input_b are used,
// then store them by OR'ing.
result |= (char)(input_b & 0x1F);
```

To read it:

```
// Simply get the lower 5 bits.
int output_b = (result & 0x1F);
```

You may want to read about the boolean operations AND and OR, bit shifting and finally *bit masks*.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, one bit can only represent two states: 0 and 1, or TRUE and FALSE. What you mean is a Byte, which consists of 8 bits and can thus represent 2^8 states.

Two put two values in one byte, use logical OR (`|`) and bitwise shift (`<<` and `>>`).

I don't post the code here since you should learn this stuff - it's really important to know what bits and bytes are and how to work with them. But feel free to ask follow up question if something is not clear to you.